# error when calling a method: error use of undeclared identifier

Tags: objective-c

So i have the below method declaration and definition,

```
  -(UIImageView *)returnImageView:(UIImageView *)myImageView color:(UIColor *)imageViewColor x:(int)xParameter y:(int)yParamater width:(int)widthParameter height:(int)heightParameter
{  
CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(xParameter, yParamater, widthParameter, heightParameter);
style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
myImageView = [myImageView initWithFrame:cellFrame];
myImageView.backgroundColor =imageViewColor;
myImageView.opaque = YES;
return myImageView;
}
```

This method will return an image view.

I am trying to call it as

```
UIImageView *myImageViews;
UIColor *tableColor = [UIColor blueColor] ;
[self.view addSubview:[returnImageView:myImageViews color:tableColor x:17 y:10 width:290 height:230];
```

which is giving a compiler error use of undeclared identifier returnImageView. What is causing the error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all a **square bracket** is missing after the last line of code.

Second you have to call "**self**" to *get* the method!

```
[self.view addSubview:[self returnImageView:myImageViews color:tableColor x:17 y:10 width:290 height:230]];
```

Third, did you **declare** your returnImageView method in the class-relative **.h file**?

```
-(UIImageView *)returnImageView:(UIImageView *)myImageView color:(UIColor *)imageViewColor x:(int)xParameter y:(int)yParamater width:(int)widthParameter height:(int)heightParameter;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes i did add the self and the method is being executed now however the image view is either not being added or the issue is with the color parameter as i cannot see  the image-view when the app runs.

Comment: The issue was the imageview was not being initialized so doing this ,

    UIImageView *myImageViews = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

Issue solved